# SQL Replace Into question

Tags: sql, mysql, replace

With Replace Into, if I have two fields.  FirstName LastName.  The table has John Smith in it, if I was to run REPLACE INTO tblNames (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (John, Jones)
Would that replace Smith with Jones, or create a new name?

What determines if its an Update or and Insert?

Answer (score 8):

```
REPLACE
INTO    tblNames (FirstName, LastName)
VALUES  ('John', 'Jones')
```

If there a unique constraint of any kind on `FirstName`, `LastName` or their combination, and it is violated, the records gets deleted and inserted with the new values.

The record will be replaced if any of the conditions is satisfied:

- `FirstName` is `UNIQUE` and there is a `John` in the table,
- `LastName` is `UNIQUE` and there is a `Jones` in the table,
- `FirstName, Lastname` is `UNIQUE` and there is a `John Jones` in the table.

Note that `REPLACE` operation is an `INSERT` possibly following a `DELETE` which will always affect the table.

In the newer versions of `MySQL`, you should use `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: So if John Smith is in the table, and I send John Jones, what sql command to I use so that it Inserts John Jones, but if I send John Smith, it does nothing.

Comment: @Matt: please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblNames`

Comment: There is not table yet.. This is hypothetical planning :)

Comment: @Greg K: Brilliant!  That's the difference between `REPLACE INTO` and `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`!! *(I was wondering)*

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the primary key and/or unique constraints are on the table.  If there is no primary key or unique contraints, it is no different from a basic INSERT statement.

The documentation gives a reasonably clear explanation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two different operators for insert and update

```
update tblNames set FirstName="John", LastName="Smith" where FirstName="John" and LastName="Jones"
```

this will rename John Jones to John Smith

```
insert into tblNames (FirstName, LastName) values ("John", "Smith")
```

this will add a new entry (but may fail if there is already John Smith in the table and there is a unique constraint on FirstName/LastName)

Comment: When i was answering there was no "mysql" tag, so my code samples are standard SQL

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the error on the insert if the record already exists?

Comment: You can perform 'select' to check if the entry already exists before doing update or insert. Not sure about MySQL but in SQL Server you can even avoid the select. The typical scenario:

update tblNames set ... where key-condition
if @@rowcount = 0 -- the number of rows affected by the last statement (i.e. update)
  insert into tblNames ....

sorry, for the late answer, hope this helps